# Attribute reshape not recognized on pickle data

Tags: python, tensorflow, ipython, pickle

I'm making a deep learning model for digit recognition from svhn dataset, my project is about 5 ipython notebooks, one of my notebooks creates a pickle file tensorflow_data.pickle, the file was created successfully but when am loading it into the container called "dataset" and using .reshape() I got this error saying : 
('Unable to process data from dataset.pickle', ':', AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'",))

---

[error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuawp.png)

---

this is my code:

```
try:
with open('tensorflow_data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    dataset = pickle.load(f)
    train_dataset = dataset['train']['data'].reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)
    test_dataset = dataset['test']['data'].reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)
    validation_dataset = dataset['valid']['data'].reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)
    extra_dataset = dataset['extra']['data'].reshape(-1, 32, 32, 1)
    train_labels = dataset['train']['label']
    test_labels = dataset['test']['label']
    validation_labels = dataset['valid']['label']
    extra_labels = dataset['extra']['label']

except Exception as e:
print('Unable to process data from dataset.pickle', ':', e)
raise
```

any help with this ? 
PS: Am using Python 2.7 with tensorflow installed on ubuntu via anaconda

Comment: At this point your code is trying to do `None.reshape(...)`.  Identify which variable is actually `None`, and figure out why that is the case.

Comment: I know this is the problem.... variable train_dataset is considered the None object and so on for validation_dataset